# Sum of 2^Pi mod 1000000007 for all i where Pi is sum of numbers in ith subset of a set X

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sets

I am stuck on a problem in which I have to print **sum of 2<sup>P<sub>i</sub></sup> mod 1000000007** for all **i** where **P<sub>i</sub>**  is sum of numbers in **i**th **subset** of a **set X**.

**Length of set** can be upto **100000**.

**Value of element** in the range **[0,10<sup>12</sup>]**.

Here's the link of the Problem.
[Problem Statement](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/the-baudelaire-predicament/description/)

I could not find any approach other than Brute-Force which gives verdict TLE.

@Moderators,admins etc.
Before putting this question on hold or marking off-Topic or closed....
Please comment the reason so that I can know the reason and if possible reword it or ask on any other StackExchange Site.
I first posted it on codegolf.stackexchange.com and people(moderators) there have suggested me to post it here as it comes under algorithm category.

You can read about it here.

[Programming Puzzles and Code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/sum-of-2pi-mod-1000000007-for-all-i-where-pi-is-sum-of-numbers-in-ith-subset-of)

Thank You

Comment: You can use LaTeX here,  Ex: $\sum 2^{P_i} \mod{1000000007}$.

Comment: I tried using it,
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

I tried both in-line and display mode but in preview, it is not showing math but the formatting itself that's why I used HTML

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71886/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/42952795/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was cross-posted to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the set you're using is $X=\{x_1,x_2, \dotsc,x_n\}$, then the expression you want to evaluate is equivalent to
$$
(2^{x_1}+1)(2^{x_2}+1)\dotsm(2^{x_n}+1)\bmod{1000000007}
$$
This isn't too hard to prove; here's an example to help you see what's going on:

Suppose $X=\{a,b,c\}$. Then the subsets of $X$ are, obviously,
$$
\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\}
$$
and the corresponding sums of elements in those subsets will be
$$
0,a,b,c,a+b,a+c,b+c,a+b+c
$$
leading to the sum
$$
2^0+2^a+2^b+2^c+2^{a+b}+2^{a+c}+2^{b+c}+2^{a+b+c}=(2^a+1)(2^b+1)(2^c+1)
$$
The general result can be established by a fairly simple induction proof.

Comment: How did you arrange the sum of subsets in factor form.Is there any standard technique for doing that or any other method?
I was not able to separate the individual terms.

Comment: @Divyanshu. If you're referring to the last display line above, it came from the fact that I recognized $1+P+Q+PQ=(P+1)(Q+1)$ and generalized from there. It's a case of remembering a trick, rather than applying a standard technique.

Comment: Yeah! This is exactly what I was looking for...
Thank You.
Let me google it, see if I can find anything related which may help in future..